# Attempt at developing a "pull mode" for a RxJS-like structure gets RangeError

Tags: javascript, node.js, data-structures, reactive-programming

I was attemting to develop a RxJS-like scheme: An event-based "observable" object. So far so good !

The problem arises when I attempted to add a "pull mode" to the scheme in addition to to the default RxJS-like push mode.

I am trying to understand what part of the code seems to use up the stack.

Here is a snippet which works fine:

```
const { Channel } = require('./channel');

var c = new Channel();

c.onClosed( (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    console.log("Done");
});

c.listen( (e) => {
    console.log(e);
});

let i = 0;
for (i=0; i<1000000; i++) {
    c.send(++i);
}
c.close(i);
```

Here is the snippet which triggers the exception:

```
const { Channel } = require('./channel');

var sc = new Channel();

let i = 0;

sc.onClosed( (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    console.log("Done");
});

sc.sendAll( () => {
    if (i<100000) {
        sc.send(++i);
        console.log(i); 
    }
    sc.close(i);
});

sc.listen( (e) => {
    console.log(e);
    sc.next();
});

sc.send(1);
```

Here is the relevant part of the lib:

```
const EventEmitter = require('events');


class Channel {

    id: string;
    emitter: any;
    isClosed: boolean;

    constructor() {
        this.emitter = new EventEmitter();
        this.isClosed = false;
    }

    listen = (callback) => {
        this.emitter.on("data", callback);
    }

    send = (value) => {
        this.emitter.emit("data", value);
    }

    next = () => {
        this.emitter.emit("received");
    }

    sendAll = (callback) => {
        this.emitter.on("received", callback);
    }

    close = (value) => {
        this.isClosed = true;
        this.emitter.emit("closed", value);
    }

    onClosed = (callback) => {
        this.isClosed = true;
        this.emitter.on("closed", callback);
    }

}


module.exports = {
    Channel: Channel
}
```

The second snippet triggers a RangeError exception if the number of iterations (the number of "send()" over the "channel" exceeds 10.000 calls)

Answer (score 0):

**Short answer**: The back and forth call between sc.sendAll() and sc.listen() creates a two-stage recursive function call of the kind:

```
function f() {
    g();
}

function g() {
    f();
}

f();
```

Because in this scheme every new event listener spawns a new callback (within a callback, etc...) recursively.

**More precisely**: Events work well for implementing "push" ("send") schemes (cf. RxJS or Kefir), but they cannot be used for a "pull" ("send and wait for confirmation") scheme (not as was intended in the original question at least).

In that sense, RxJS observables or Node events (more generally JavaScript reactive data structure) differ from iterators : The observable has to deal with the incoming data stream "as is" (and not "on-demand"). In that sense also the proposed "channel" structure of the initial post differs from a Golang channel in the sense that it does not have a "blocking" mode.

**Conclusion** : A golang-like "channel" object can be implemented in JavaScript using Node events, but it cannot be made "blocking" using the same scheme.